# How to convert char * to unsigned int in C programming in win32

Tags: c, string, integer, unsigned

I am trying to convert char *str = "10.20.30.40" ; in to unsigned int . can u pls tell me any method is there or any sample code . pls share me.

Comment: 10.20.30.40 is not a number - what do you want to convert it to? 10203040?

Comment: Looks like it could be an IP4 address?

Comment: Dave: Yes, that's actually quite possible.

Answer (score 6):

Guessing at what you actually want to do, take a look at the functions `inet_addr` and `inet_aton`.